# .htaccess - How to insert string into address if a string does not exist in URL

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am looking to redirect url's in a multi-lingual site if it doesn't contain a language string. For example, if the url comes in as:

http://www.example.com/overview/features

I would like to redirect it to

http://www.example.com/en/overview/features

... i.e. insert the 'en' language string into the url. If it does contain the string then it is left alone.

I hazard a guess this is using negative look backs/forwards, but my .htaccess skills don't seem to be up to the above scenario.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `(?!(en|es|fr|de|gr)/)` for example.

Comment: Hey mario, thanks for the hint, that I assume would be the condition, but how would I write the rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I think we are pretty close with this one Jon thanks. The only issue now is for the local set up, which has the site in a folder ... something like http://localhost/example/overview/features ... the above converts it to http://localhost/en/overview/features (i.e. strips the sites folder name) ... any ideas?

Comment: @AdamJowett Are you putting those rules in the **document root**? e.g. where you'd go to if you went to `http://localhost/`?

Comment: Those rules are sitting in a .htaccess file sitting at the root of the web structure. i.e. for my wamp setup in c:/wamp/www/examplesite

Comment: @AdamJowett if it's in the document root, no idea why the `example` part isn't being captured by the `(.*)`, since that's essentially everything in the URI. I guess replace `$1` with `%{REQUEST_URI}` then